# ASP .net Core SignOutAsync issue

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, logging, authorization, logout

Below code is really working for login and logout. But i am facing an issue,

1. Ran the application with chrome and login with **A user**. Successfully logged in
2. He opened another tab it is not asking for login. Because he already logged in with previous tab, it took that cookies.

   **A user** navigating to **purchase menu** in that new tab. He has rights to open this menu and do purchase order.

   He clicked logged out from the first tab and it is successfully logged out. The second tab still opened with purchase screen.

   Now **User B** Successfully logged in with his credential. He doesn't have purchase activity rights.

   He opened that purchase screen tab and placed an order it is successfully placed

I want to restrict this by when ever expired session/cookies come to server we have to ignore and redirect to login screen.

 
Login code
```
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, u.Name),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, u.DisplayName),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, JsonSerializer.Serialize(u)),
                }, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);
```
Logout code
```
public async Task Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```
Startup.cs
```

```
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(x =>
            {
                x.LoginPath = "/UserAccount";
                x.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                x.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });


        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> He opened that purchase screen tab and placed an order it is
> successfully placed

Add `[Authorize]` to the action which place an order.

Below is a demo, I add a link to aa action in Confidential.cshtml. If first tab user log out , the second tab user cannot go to the aa action.

HomeController:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult ConfidentialData() 
        {
            return View();    
        }
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult aa()
        {
            return Ok(3);
        }
    }
```

Confidential.cshtml:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        @foreach (var claim in User.Claims) {
        <tr><td>@claim.Type</td><td>@claim.Value</td></tr>
        }
    </table>
   <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="aa">Home</a></li>
    
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort.

I cannot add Authorize attribute to each and ever action, so that i already added AuthorizationPolicyBuilder from startup.cs. 

The issue you are not reproduced yet. 

1) After logout Don't do any action (don't click home Link) from second tab.
2) Login with some other user which is not having confidential data rights but having home page rights. Then come to second tab and click confidential data.

Comment: @Prakash This is a link I just named home, it's actually aa action not index , I replace placed an order with aa. Then come to second tab and click confidential data, the user B cannot open the  confidential data after user a log out.  If you cannot add Authorize attribute to each and ever action, could you show you other code , so that I can reproduce your problem.